# Creating a new editable region in opencart

Tags: opencart

Ive created/hard coded an extra section of information to the product page template in opencart, but this isn't ideal, so I need to link this section to the admin so that the information contained can be edited on a per product basis from within the admin interface.

What would I need to go about doing to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a fair bit to do but not that onerous, in short (assuming it is an additional description):

Add a new field to the database (probably on the product_description table);

Add the new language variables to the language file:

```
../admin/language/english/catalog/product.php
```

Add the new description/field to the template:

```
../admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl
```

Add the variable definitions/post code etc to the controller file:

```
../admin/controller/catalog/product.php
```

Edit the database queries to include the new field (at least Add, edit and delete functions:

```
../admin/model/catalog/product.php
```

If it is a description based field then if you search those files for 'description' and then replicate the code, substituting for your new field name, that should do it.